# How to construct SQL query for this...?

Tags: sql

I would like to do some math operation but for each row at the time.

For example:

```
A         B        C         D
-------------------------------
100      -50       =50      20160101 
100       0        =150     20160102
100      -50       =100     20160103
```

So basically column C would always be sum of all past A +(B) columns, but not future ones. Does anyone have idea on how to achieve this in SQL?

I can do this in code, but I would like to do this in SQL and just show result in table.

P.S. my english is not the best, so feel free to ask if I was not clear enough.

Comment: What year SQL Server?

Comment: Didn't understand what column c does, why the second one is 150 and the third is 100

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a cumulative or running sum.  The normal method uses ANSI standard window functions:

```
select a, b,
       sum(a + b) over (order by d) as c,
       d
from t;
```

If your version of SQL doesn't support window functions, then you can use a correlated subquery (performance would generally be much worse):

```
select a, b,
       (select sum(a + b) from t t2 where t2.d <= t.d) as c,
       d
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you, second solution works perfectly, just added order by d at the end .